# Dynamic Memory allocation C

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

My problem requires conversion of fixed Array size to dynamic memory allocation. I have tried all sorts of calloc, malloc and relloc statements but nothing seemed to work. I guess even a void *data pointer was useless.

Please convert this code for dynamic memory so that I can resize the array later. Also to add I am working with linked list so this array is a Node pointer.

```
Node *lists[100]  //this does my job 
lists[listNo] = NULL;
```

if I want to use malloc:

```
Node *lists = (Node) malloc(100*sizeof(Node));
lists[listNo] = NULL; // gives me error when I use malloc or calloc and the error is assigning Node from void*
```

Comment: Are you perhaps using a C++ compiler for C code? Try `#ifdef __cplusplus` `#error wrong compiler` `#endif`

Comment: I am using C compiler only

Comment: Could you show the code where you sue malloc and you get an error ? Do you get a compilation error or an error when executing the code ?

Comment: You cannot assign a pointer to an object (`Node_var = pointer`); if `Node_var` is a pointer, assigning it a value of type `void*` is ok in C

Comment: You are using a c++ compiler... in c `void *` is converted to any poitner type...

Comment: `Node *lists = (Node) malloc` stop right here. Do you want a `Node*` or a `Node`?

Comment: @n.m. Compare with its code above that works and the assignment of NULL that it tries to do. lists is an array of pointers. This is what it tries to malloc.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that lists should be defined as a pointer to an array of pointers when using malloc.

```
 Node **lists = malloc(100*sizeof(Node*));
 lists[listNo] = NULL;
```

Comment: @AbhishekSingh please don't forget to check that the allocation succeeded.

Comment: @chmike Though the above fixes the error and works fine but I am unable to get successful results with checking memory allocation. I tried giving Node **lists = malloc(1*sizeof(Node*)); This also works for 4 lists as inputs. So I am bit confused now

Comment: What do you mean by "checking memory allocation" ? With `Node *lists = malloc(1*sizeof(Node));` you declare `list` as a pointer to a Node structure and you allocate a buffer of the size of a single Node structure. In this case list is a pointer to one Node, not to an array (list) of Node.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your assertion that:

```
Node *lists[100]
```

...does the job, then that's an array of 100 pointers (to type `Node`).  The usual variable-length version of that is:

```
Node **lists; /* points to first pointer in dynamic array */
int lists_size; /* you need a variable to hold the size */
```

If the array is very large, use `size_t` from `<stdlib.h>` instead of int, but int is easier to use with small arrays and index variables.  Allocate that with:

```
lists_size = 100; /* replace 100 with a computed size */
lists = (Node**)calloc(lists_size, sizeof (Node*));
```

Use `lists_size` in place of 100 in your code and everything else will work the same.  Use of calloc() instead of malloc() will clear the allocated memory to binary zeroes, eliminating the need for loop to store NULL pointers on every actual implementation.  (Technically, the C standard doesn't require NULL to be zero, or at least didn't the last time I looked, but a few megatons of Unix plus Windows code requires this.)

Comment: `calloc(a, b);` can solve some alignment problems `malloc(a * b);` doesn't, also.

Comment: @LuisColorado This is news to me.  Can you give an example? I can't think of one that doesn't involve me guessing the `sizeof` of an object and guessing wrong.

Comment: Suppose you make a packed structure and you want to create an array of these structures.  Some compiler **can pad** the structure elements when building the array and not when defining a variable of only one instance of this type.  **calloc(3)** as a system function, can support and add the right padding to the element size before allocating memory for the array.  I'm not able to illustrate this now on a portable way, but I was in the past.